# SQL converting column from Latin1 to UTF8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, latin, collate

I am trying to convert a specific column in a table on my DB from latin1 character set with collation latin1_swedish_ci to utf8 with collation utf8_unicode_ci.

COLUMN: description, type: longtext, default not null

I tried the following commands on the column:

```
ALTER TABLE sample MODIFY description LONGBLOB NOT NULL ;

ALTER TABLE sample MODIFY description LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I also tried to alter the encoding WITHOUT changing to binary first. But the characters ended up being re-encoded incorrectly by the server.

And keep getting an error regarding some characters:

> Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\x92t hav...' for column 'longDesc' at row 803

It seems like some of the character in my table aren't converting correctly.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: ***WHAT*** database??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\x92 implies that you have latin1 in the table *now*.  The second ALTER is *claiming* that the bytes are in utf8 encoding.  Hence, the error message.

Case 1:  You need to change the LONGTEXT to utf8 because you plan to add rows with text that cannot be encoded in latin1.

For this case, `ALTER TABLE sample CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;` -- converts all CHAR/TEXT columns in the table.

`ALTER TABLE sample MODIFY description ... CHARACTER SET utf8;` -- converts the one column.

Case 2:  The rest of the system is thinking utf8 and is confused by this column.

Well, I don't think it is confused.  Conversions happen as needed.